# Shell script: Syntax error: Redirection unexpected:what is the alternate of "<<<" in shell?

Tags: string, bash, shell

Here is my code:

```
f="\bkg\inp.txt"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    IFS='|' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
    #echo "${array[0]}"
    if [ "${array[2]}" == "Sangamithra" ]; then
        printf "%s" "${array[2]}|" "${array[1]}|"${array[0]}"
    fi

done < "$f"
```

I know what the error is...
Since I am new to shell scripting..
I found the code in stackoverflow where we split a string and put into array - But the `<<<` part is causing problem showing `Syntax error : Redirection unexpected`..
Now wht should be the replacement for  "<<<" in shell script or I have to choose any other way?I am not very much aware of all the syntaxes so could not replace..

Any help is very much appreaciated!!

Comment: Make sure the number of quotation marks is even.

Comment: yes those are all ok, because the code is running in another bash environment..But only in sh it is causing problem @Cyrus

Comment: You tagged this question `bash`, but your comment seems to indicate that the error only happens when you run the code with a non-bash shell. So which shell are you actually using?

Comment: I am using sh shell and running with sh script.sh

Comment: `sh` is not `bash`; support for `<<<` simply isn't required by POSIX.

Comment: `sh` doesn't support arrays, either, or the use of `==` inside `[ ... ]`.

Comment: I also strongly recommend fixing your input files so that they are proper POSIX text files (by ending with a newline), rather than using the `|| [ -n $line ]]` hack.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative for `<<< "STRING"` is `echo "STRING"` but if you pipe
the output of `echo` to the `read` command as `echo "$line" | read ..`,
`read` will be invoked in subshell,
in which created variables are not accessible from outside of the subshell.
Then please try:

```
f="\bkg\inp.txt"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    IFS='|' read -r -a array < <(echo "$line")
    if [ "${array[2]}" == "Sangamithra" ]; then
        printf "%s" "${array[2]}|${array[1]}|${array[0]}"
    fi
done < "$f"
```

If you are executing `sh`, not `bash`, the script
above will **also complain** about the redirect.
Then please consider to switch to `bash`, or try the following `sh` compliant
version:

```
#!/bin/sh

f="\bkg\inp.txt"
while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    IFS="|" set -- $line
    if [ "$3" = "Sangamithra" ]; then
        printf "%s" "$3|$2|$1"
    fi
done < "$f"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Rather than overwrite the script's positional parameters with `set`, just let `read` to the splitting. `read -r a b c _` will set `a`, `b`, and `c` to the first 3 fields, with any leftover input assigned to the dummy variable `_`.